# Matlab interface for minpack2

Tags: matlab, least-squares

Is there a Matlab interface for minpack2?
minpack2 http://ftp.mcs.anl.gov/pub/MINPACK-2 consists of Fortran programs , but i would like to call the test problems from matlab.
What can i do ?

Comment: Does this mean you've tried using matlab's built-in optimization toolbox and you were unsatisfied with the results? Or do you have legacy code using minpack2 that you think would be easiest to port? Can you edit your question to further explain your situation, because there may be other options we could suggest that you haven't thought of. Like [minFunc](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~schmidtm/Software/minFunc.html) for instance.

Comment: I would like to use some fortran subroutines from MINPACK2-test function for my optimization toolbox in MATLAB

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the existence of Matlab interface for original Fortran version of MINPACK-2. However, [Dr. Shaun Forth](https://www.cranfield.ac.uk/people/dr-shaun-forth-806215) at some point was working on Matlab implementation of Minpack-2 test problem suite, including the library itself.

Here are a couple of his relevant conference papers:

- Forth S, "A Matlab Implementation of the Minpack-2 Test Problem Collection," in *18th European W. Automatic Differentiation*, Paderborn, Nov. 2015.
- Forth S, ["A Matlab implementation of the Minpack-2 Test Problem Collection,"](http://www.autodiff.org/ad16/Oral/Forth_Matlab.pdf) in *7th Int. Conf. Algorithmic Differentiation*, Oxford, Sept. 2016.